# Use regular expression extractor variable in Tear Down Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

we have to save regular expression extractor variable in one file --> "GJC_NUMZCAISSE" Type="Integer" Value="(.+?)"/>

Data Used for StoreClosing Transaction : Closing - cbrauth,store,baid,GJC_NUMZCAISSE
GJC_NUMZCAISSE variable will fetch from Login and save into one file and use corresponded data for closing as written above.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

Regular expression extractor produces a JMeter Variable which is visible only to the Thread Group where it's declared.

If you want to access the variable value in the tearDown Thread Group you need to convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty).

The property value can be read using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) where required

[image]

More information: [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups/)